# Mailgun: Sending image using parse cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mailgun

I have a code defined as

```
Parse.Cloud.define("mailgunSendMail", function(request, response) {

               var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
               Mailgun.initialize('photoshare.com', 'APPKey');

               Mailgun.sendEmail({
                                 to: "toTestUser@mail.com",
                                 from: "fromTestUser@mail.com",
                                 subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
                                 text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!",
                                 attachment:"ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
                                 }, {
                                 success: function(httpResponse) {
                                 console.log(httpResponse);
                                 response.success("Email sent!");
                                 },
                                 error: function(httpResponse) {
                                 console.error(httpResponse);
                                 response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
                                 }
                                 });
               });
```

Mail was sent successfully and recipient got the mail but the attachment is missing. How can i send attachment in the form of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to parse, at this point there is no way to send attachments in an email. [Check this link](https://www.parse.com/questions/sending-an-attachment-using-parsecom-cloudcode-and-mailgun)

However, if you can include your image file in your HTML code like this if this serves your needs.

```
html: '<html><body style="text-align:center;"><img border="0" src="http://files.parse.com/6ffa6b80-d0eb-401f-b663-22d4a16df004/bfed9ac4-058c-41fc-a0f1-fb6155572c12-ad77a082-453f-42f7-94ef-40c3f3e885e6.png" alt="Pulpit rock" width="300" height="150"></body></html>'
```

Comment: How can i insert image url got from request parameter to this html string ?

Comment: you could do like this  html: '<html><body style="text-align:center;"><img border="0" src=' + request.object.get('htmlString') + 'alt="rock" width="300" height="150"></body></html>'

Answer (score 0):

Subash answer is right. I just edited to my question:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("mailgunSendMail", function(request, response) {
           var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
           Mailgun.initialize('photoshare.com', 'AppKey');

           Mailgun.sendEmail({
                             to: "toTestuser@mail.com",
                             from: "fromTestUser@mail.com",
                             subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
                             text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!",
                             html: '<html><body><img src="' + request.params.imageUrlKey + '"></body></html>'                                 }, {
                             success: function(httpResponse) {
                             console.log(httpResponse);
                             response.success("Email sent!");
                             },
                             error: function(httpResponse) {
                             console.error(httpResponse);
                             response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
                             }
                             });
           });
```

Where `imageUrlKey` is a parameter key which contains image url.